# Does $\int{f(x)\cdot f'(x)}dx=\frac{f^2(x)}{2}+c$ work?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, chain-rule

$$\int{f(x) \cdot f'(x)dx}=\frac{f^2(x)}{2}+c$$
Does this rule always work, as it appears this way to me.
$$\int{y\frac{dy}{dx}dx}=\int{ydy}=\frac{y^2}{2}+c$$
This is my working so far but I was wondering if this works for all functions or are there some limitations?

Comment: (1)  It is just a $u$-substitution and (2) you could check the answer by differentiation and notice that it is correct.

Comment: your second line is essentially a proof that it works.

Comment: certainly for the functions I have tried it is true and I cannot see why it would not be true for all functions $f(x)$ but not sure if anyone else knew better?

Comment: No, it does not always work.  There are functions $f(x)$, with  derivatives $f'(x)$, that exist and are bounded everywhere, but are not Riemann integrable.  See [Volterra's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Comment: @Randall This is not generally true   See [Volterra's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).  One needs to ensure that $f'(x)$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: OK, fine.  Assuming the integral exists, yes.

Comment: @MarkViola You bring up an interesting subtlety. Does an *indefinite* integral involve any concept of integrability, or is it just another way of stating that one function is the derivative of another?

Comment: ah I see now, this was what I meant for if it always works or not. If this was to be used how would you know whether or not it works?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I interpret the symbol $\int$ as an integral, and prefer to write $\int_a^x f(t)f'(t)\,dt$.  If it merely means here a function that has as its derivative $f(x)f'(x)$, then yes, $\frac12 f^2(x)$+C $ is it.

Comment: @MarkViola That is interesting. I happen to take the other point of view.

Comment: @UmbertoP. In taking that "other point of view," the symbol $\int$ can no longer be interpreted as an integral.  It becomes merely a pure symbol.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It is a convenient abuse of notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=f(x)$, then $du= f'(x)dx.$

Thus  $$\int{f(x) \cdot f'(x)dx}=  \int{udu} = \frac {u^2}{2}+c  =     \frac{f^2(x)}{2}+c $$

Comment: How does one know that $f'$ is integrable?  Volterra's Function is an example of a function that is differentiable everywhere, has a bounded derivative everywhere, but is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: This is an indefinite  integral which is simply  an antiderivative.

Comment: It's an integral.  So, we'll agree to disagree